# Dell recision M6500::Get flashing dash on black screen after memory test

Tags: windows-7, boot, laptop, memory, bios

Dell precision M6500 :: quad core i7 :: Nvidia quatro 2800

Took out working ram to clean vents. They were working fine, but fans would not go off or reduce in response to lowered web pages/program demands. Researched this problem and found the videos vents might be the problem. Found a YouTube showing how to break it down to get to vents to clean. put it back together without problems until I restarted.

- It starts up.
- Shows the Dell M6500 screen with a memory test.
- Once completed without any errors it goes to a black screen with a flashing - underscore in the top left-hand side of the screen.

Rebooted several times with the same results.

I read in other places online that the bios might need to be flushed to get it to recognize the ram, but it's not new ram and it worked great before, so I think it's unlikely both of them suddenly went bad at the same time.

I have no idea how to "flush" the Bios. Should I take out the ram, have it read that the ram is missing or bee like it would on a desktop PC?

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Have you tried with a single RAM.

Comment: Taking out and re-inserting the RAM does solve such problems in a large number of cases, but do it only if the laptop is out of warranty and you have nothing to lose. Otherwise, its best to call the pros to do their job :-).